# How to handle "unable to connect..." in retrofit?

Tags: android, api, retrofit

So i'm using retrofit to connect my application to server. I have some issue, it is when device doesn't have connetivity , it returns "unable to connect myservername.dev.com" . I dont know how to solve it. I already solved the "no connectivity" issue but still when there is no connection sometimes it returns "unable to connect..." . Any solution? i'm kinda depressed cause i found nothing in google.

this is how i connect my app with retrofit :

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://myserver.com/admin/api/";
public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getApi(final Context context){

    OkHttpClient defaultHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
                @Override
                public Response intercept(Interceptor.Chain chain) throws IOException {
                    //getAccessToken is your own accessToken(retrieve it by saving in shared preference or any other option )
                    String accessToken = SharedPreferenceManager.getToken(context);
                    if(accessToken.isEmpty()){
                        Log.e("retrofit 2","User Token is Empty");
                        return chain.proceed(chain.request());
                    }
                    Request authorisedRequest = chain.request().newBuilder()
                            .addHeader("APP_TOKEN", "myservertoken")
                            .addHeader("USER_TOKEN", accessToken)
                            .addHeader("Content_Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                            .build();
                    Log.e("retrofit 2","User Token : " + accessToken);
                    return chain.proceed(authorisedRequest);
                }}).addInterceptor(new ConnectivityInterceptor(context)).
                    readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    if(retrofit == null){
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(defaultHttpClient)
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

Comment: what is the expected behaviour when there is no connectivity?

Comment: App show toast saying "No Connectivity"

Answer (score 0):

Before hit api you can check your device have connectivity or not, then hit the api

```
public boolean isNetworkAvialable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm =
                (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
    }
```

this method return true if your device have connectivity other then it return false.

and add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Add this method for waiting server response

```
if (retrofit == null) {

            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();

            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
                    .connectTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .writeTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                    .build();

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(ApplicationConstant.INSTANCE.BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
```

and add this dependency

`implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'`

Comment: i've handle this. It returns "No Connectivity" but when sometimes it returns "unable to connect...".

Comment: when you getting No Connectivity then you don't hit API

Comment: let me make this clear to you. I already handle when device has no connectivity and it returns "No Connectivity". It works perfectly but sometimes it return "Unable to Connect...." . what i'm asking about is that how to handle that?

Comment: ok i understand, so want to inform you that it's back end or server side problem. when server did not get your request so it return Unable to connect.

Comment: and you can use this method for getting response if client does not connect to server

Comment: yes i undestand . so how to handle it? how to avoid it from popping on the screen?

Comment: i already added that syntax on my code and it works. But sometimes my app show toast "unable to connect..."

Comment: Add `HttpLoggingInterceptor` method according to answer

Comment: Ok i'll try that one. Thanks for the answers though